# Advantages / Disadvantages of pconnect option in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, performance, codeigniter

One of the parameters in the CodeIgniter database config is the following

```
['pconnect'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether to use a persistent connection
```

What do you recommend I set this to?
Is there a significant performance hit if I set it to FALSE?
What potential problems might arise from setting it to TRUE?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Just look up general best practices for persistent connections. My suggestions.

- By default, DO NOT
- If you have:

  - Dedicated web server and database hardware in production
  - and have tuned the web server and database correctly
  - and have an accurate production-like test environment
  - And still think your performance problems are caused by database connection time,

CONSIDER turning it on

Persistent connections can cause

- Bugs because some connection state persisted unintentionally (this is a biggie!)
- Database connection limits to be exceeded
- Database performance to drop because of lots of ram used by the many (mostly idle) connections
- Bugs because connections have gone "stale" and the app didn't notice

But CAN

- Reduce latency on initial connection

If you think that connection latency is causing a problem, consider turning it on in your performance test system and *measuring* the impact.

Comment: Can I just add that you can use connection pooling but that this ntroduces its own set of issues to adress and I'm not sure that codeigniter can handle them. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-ms.php