# More than max_user_connections in CodeIgniter app?

Tags: php, database-connection, codeigniter-2

I'm getting what looks like rather serious database errors in my CodeIgniter application. In the log file it says:

User anders already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

And there are several hundred of those lines... I've read a bit by Googling, and some suggested that it was because you didn't close the connection after it was used, but others said that this was nonsense, and that the connection was automatically closed (which is what I read in the docs too).

Also, later in the log file, I have these error messages:

ERROR - 2011-10-12 10:50:19 --> Severity: Warning  --> file_get_contents(http://localhost/expertinfo/error/error_general) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/expertinfo/application/errors/error_general.php 4

This seems to have something to do with the fact that I'm using a custom error page by using

```
echo file_get_contents($config['base_url'] . 'error/error_db');
```

to redirect to a custom page.

Finally, I'm also getting:

ERROR - 2011-10-12 10:52:19 --> Severity: Warning  --> mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mydb24.surftown.se' (4) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/expertinfo/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php 88

In these last two, I don't understand what the local path is doing there (The path to my CodeIgniter app on my computer). I mean this is a part of the system folder and the one on the remote server should be used, right? I have the database set up as the remote database, and I don't have any local paths as far as I know....

So why does this happen, and what can I do about it?

Please help, this seems rather urgent. I'm a bit of a newbie to both php and CodeIgniter too, so a clear and simple answer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local path as I see shows you file where your error happened, because your driver `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/expertinfo/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php` possible on it's 88 line contain connect() function and it raise an exception

The problem is with your `mydb24.surftown.se` remote server, you should check your access credentials, etc. to find what exactly happened

Comment: Yes, you're right. There was apparently a database connection problem at the web host, but they wouldn't admit it or didn't know it, because the problem just went away by itself eventually...

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, mysql_pconnect is usually a bad practice on shared hosting (you can see why here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830830/advantages-disadvantages-of-pconnect-option-in-codeigniter)
You might just disable pconnect on application/config/database.php and see the error going away as your connections will be realluy lower.

Answer (score 0):

For the quote: "mysql_pconnect is usually a bad practice on shared hosting".
I changed to use mysql_connect. It made no difference.