# Can not connect to MySQL with CodeIgniter. Possible DNS issue?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am running a dev LAMP with Codeigniter.  However, when I try to load the page, the  database can not connect(the database is actually on another server) and I get this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

My database.php is this:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'myhost.com';
$db['default']['username'] = 'myusername';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mytable';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

If I change the 'pconnect' and/or 'db_debug' to false, I get the same error or it just doesn't work. I know the database is up and running correctly because others are able to connect and use it.

However, if I put the IP address of the host into the database.php file, it works.
I tried flushing the DNS and even changed to Google's DNS servers to no avail.

The result of a simple mysql_connect is:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service    not known

Filename: config/database.php

Line Number: 67

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_connect(): [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or     service not known (trying to connect via tcp://myhost.com:3306)

Filename: config/database.php

Line Number: 67

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Filename: config/database.php

Line Number: 67

Could not connect: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Comment: Have you tried to isolate the issue by making a small PHP file with just a [mysql_connect](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) call in it?

Comment: Added the reslults of a mysql_connect to the main question.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830830/advantages-disadvantages-of-pconnect-option-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

Try change this

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

to this:

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the domain name is registered to the correct I.P. address and your host has the record of this exact address. Try placing a static HTML file on the website, all you need is something that displays maybe the text "Hello World" to ensure that you are able to access the website via the domain name.

Ensure that you have inserted the domain name correctly in the script and that you can log in to PHPMyAdmin (or whatever you use) with the required credentials via copy and paste (without leading and trailing whitespace, be careful of that).

If it is a problem with the table name, it should say so. As for the rest of the settings, I am not familiar with any of them, but what I have outlined here should see your database working.

Good luck.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is working with copy/pasting the credentials from the database.php. I received the exact IP for the host via a nslookup command.

Comment: Run a whois on the domain name and see what I.P. it returns. That could be your issue.
Also, I assume that you just changed the domain name in the error log to myhost.com?
If the I.P. address checks out correct, check you have the right port, and also try ftp.myhost.com

Comment: I ran the nslookup command on the domain name and received an IP.  It works if I define hostname with the IP address.  And yes, I changed the hostname to 'myhost.com' for the post.  All the ports in use are the defaults and I tried 'ftp.myhost.com' to no effect.     And finally, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Ok, well firstly, is it the same I.P.?
Also, can you get away with using the hostname or not? It would be worth using the hostname if this is a live website. It appears that you are using PHP? The following code works for me:
$mysqli = new mysqli($_CONF['db']['host'], $_CONF['db']['user'], $_CONF['db']['pass'], $_CONF['db']['dflt']);
Where I have already predfined those settings. Have you tried this command?