# errors in database and requeste not allowed using codeigniter

Tags: database, .htaccess, codeigniter, config

I am using codeigniter and I was having a problem in .htaccess file then when the site opened an error appear:

> A Database Error Occurred  Unable to connect to your database server
>   using the provided settings.  Filename: core/Loader.php  Line Number:
>   346

I searched for the solution and I get that:

database.php file:

`$db[‘default’][‘db_debug’] = TRUE` change it to `$db[‘default’][‘db_debug’] = FALSE`

It works to open the view files but no action with database it gives an error
and another solution that didn't work was
database file:
`$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;` set to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `$db[‘default’][‘db_debug’] = FALSE` It means it hides your database errors but It does not mean your database errors will solve.

The error message you got says the real reason what problem you are getting

Open your `config/database.php` and check the database credential(`hostname,username,password,database,dbdriver` and may be others) you provided is OK.The error message says they are not OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you have you application online, you need to hide DB errors because of security reasons. 
Change DB config to:

```
$db[‘default’][‘db_debug’] = FALSE;
```

If you are in development mode, you can use Profiler to check every query and everything. Just add this in controller:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

And for `pconncet`, you have a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1831310/966933)