# Wordpress slow on azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Wordpress site hosted in a `Basic` (small) Azure Web App with ClearDb (Titan). I also have another Web App hosted in this `Basic` service plan using Azure SQL DB. I had some latency issues with that, but ultimately using persistent connections they got solved ([Azure web app slow server response time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414284/azure-web-app-slow-server-response-time)).

Given that the other app works great and the Wordpress site also works fine once the page gets loaded I think the issue might be with the database connection. I tried hosting `MySql` in a docker image on Azure VM, but the performance did not improve.

Note that when the site is cold the page loads in around **20 seconds**. I would be happy if this could be driven down to somewhere around 1-2 seconds.

I tried setting `output_buffering = Off;`, but no improvement at all. I also have AlwaysOn enabled.

Any suggestions how could I improve the latency?

Comment: you can try to use https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/10-ways-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site-on-azure-websites/ to optimize your wordpress site

Comment: Hey Gary, I already tried most of the points here, but as my question says I have the biggest issues with cold starts - even though I have AlwaysOn enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Try to enable Always On in the Settings. 20 seconds is a very serious number, but Always On should eliminate the issue with the cold start.

UPD: Next step - enable Application Insights (performance monitoring in the settings) to see what is going on with your performance. It is really difficult to say what can be a problem - you can check if your DB and your website are in the same region (however, i did not experience such numbers because of that).

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I have AlwaysOn enabled.

Comment: Will Application Insights work? When I enabled it it says it's for .net apps and most of the code is in 'C#'. Only the browser page load data tile can be used with `js`. I'll try to set it up.

Comment: Ouch, then there is something wrong elsewhere. Yes, what is great about AppInsights that you can use it for that. Take a look at how to configure the module. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/usage-analytics-for-wordpress-with-azure-app-insights/

Comment: I've tried to follow trough the tutorial, it might take some more time, because you need an organizational account to set up AppInsights and parts of the tutorial are very vague - i.e. you need to set up additional services available only to organizational accounts, but there are no linked tutorials.

Comment: @Pio by the way, did you see that? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/10-ways-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site-on-azure-websites/

Answer (score 4):

It is due to PHP's output buffering, which is not configured on Azure WebApp.
To resolve this you can add the following code in the web.config file and restart your WebApp.

```
<configuration>
      <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
            <add name="PHP-FastCGI"
                path="*.php"
                verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
                modules="FastCgiModule"
                scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe"
                resourceType="Either"
                requireAccess="Script" 
                responseBufferLimit="0" />
         </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You reference a local drive `scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe"`
Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this reference for improving WordPress Performance on Azure Web Apps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/05/15/improving-wordpress-performance-on-azure-web-apps/

Comment: link no longer exists. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was putting both the webapp and the db (azure mysql) into the same region. Before I did that - everything was extremely slow but once I recreated the app with both resources in the same region the app became very snappy.

The first time I created the app, it's resource group was in the Central US, but apparently the azure mysql is not available there at this stage so I had to put the db somewhere else which caused the slowness.

I also turned on the "always on" option.

[image]