# How to fix "Unable to select the specified database" in xampp and code igniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, xampp

I'm having a problem in codeigniter message "Unable to select the specified database Filename: E:\xampp\htdocs\marketingtools\system\database\DB_driver.php"

My database is existing and the credentials are correct because most of the time the program runs properly and then suddenly the error occur I don't know what is happening because i did not change anything in xampp settings and codeigniter settings but the error happens and ill wait for a while the program runs properly again.

here is the sample of my code

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root'; //aims_prog
$db['default']['password'] = ''; //yqUMaEBrvM8j6emD
$db['default']['database'] = 'marketingtools';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I would not use persistent connections unless I had to. Maybe interesting? [Advantages / Disadvantages of pconnect option in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830830/advantages-disadvantages-of-pconnect-option-in-codeigniter)

Comment: is there any chances that there are too many users and something become full thats why the error occur

Comment: you would need to collect stats from the database to find that out. Have you looked at the database logs?