# Codeigniter session query in mysql slow query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm maintaining a heavy traffic web app providing RESTFul API using codeigniter and mysql.
After turning mysql slow query log with 1 second long query time following query is login repeatedly with execution time of 100+ seconds.

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('fhn1enbb1u9hgu4m1tq32fbsds4c8ohj', 300) AS ci_session_lock;
```

It seems something with codeigniter configuration please help.

## Sample slow query log:

```
SET timestamp=1554912062;
SELECT GET_LOCK('fhn1enbb1u9hgu4m1tq32fbsds4c8ohj', 300) AS ci_session_lock;
Time: 2019-04-10T16:01:02.640796Z
Query_time: 99.819745  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0

SET timestamp=1554912062;
SELECT GET_LOCK('taff1quqs4gv2g33740t41cdplnpkof8', 300) AS ci_session_lock;
Time: 2019-04-10T16:01:03.082128Z
Query_time: 94.859307  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0

SET timestamp=1554912061;
SELECT GET_LOCK('fhn1enbb1u9hgu4m1tq32fbsds4c8ohj', 300) AS ci_session_lock;
Time: 2019-04-10T16:01:01.979967Z
Query_time: 106.766586  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at this [archive from the old CodeIgniter forum](https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-64893.html), it looks like normal behavior.

> You can just ignore this.
>
> It's caused by the same user attempting to simultaneously load multiple pages (or one page with asynchronous AJAX calls) on your website. And it's exactly what is supposed to happen - wait for the lock to be freed (session closed on one page) before being able to acquire a lock for the second page load.
>
> Concurrent users and the database engine are irrelevant. You didn't see this on MyISAM just because you didn't have a user with the same behavior during that temporary switch.

This is basically because CodeIgniter uses persistent database connection by default. This is set by the [`pconnect` option](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html):

```php
$db['default'] = array(
    ...
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    ...
);
```

Since the lock is not released by the connection, another page trying to load will wait for the lock to be freed...

You could try to disable the persistent connection. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1831310/8861729) gives a pretty good explanation on when and why enabling persistent connection.

Comment: I wonder...  Is it CogeIgniter's fault for not clearing `GETLOCKs`?  Or is CI using some connection polling mechanism, and _that_ is at fault?

Comment: Even if CodeIgniter is clearing its locks (and it seems it does), if a user is loading 2 pages simultaneously, there are still chances one page will hit a lock... However, looking at OP's query log, I wonder what could really cause a 100 seconds delay..

Comment: 'pconnect' => false,
But still  some queries of set_lock goes in sleep mode?? can anyone tell me why??? Thanks

Comment: Yeah this is happening several "fetch" requests (like the AJAX calls what @Indigo mentioned.